# Probability Of finding real roots

Tags: probability

If the coefficient of the quadratic equation ax²+bx+c=0 are determine by throwing an unbiased dice what is the probability of finding real roots of the equation.

Comment: Yuo need to find $P(b^2-4ac)\geq 0$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. I changed the [tag:probability-theory] tag to [tag:probability]. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries in choosing tags.